# Why can i send a Post via Postman but not via the JS/JQUERY CLIENT

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, post, postman

Ok i have a nodeJs/Express Webservice and when i send a post to the webservice via Postman it works put when i send a post with JS it didnt work. I get the Error {message: "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"}

Ok when i send a post via Postman to http://localhost:5000/api/users
and in the body there is this userImage in the form data field and it work. but when i send it via JS client i get the Error

ok this is the JS CLIENT

```
$("#registerUser").click(async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let image = $("#fileToUpload").val();


    let number = $("#phone").val();
    let username = $("#username").val();
    let firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    let lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    let password = $("#password").val();
    let email = $("#email").val();
    let level = $("#user_level").val();
    let data = JSON.stringify({
      userImage: image,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      email: email,
      phone: number,
      role: level
    });
    console.log(data);
    registerUser(data);
  });

async function registerUser(data) {
    try {
      console.log(data);

      let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/users", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: cookie
        },
        body: data
      });
      let result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error: " + e.message);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must :

- In server : add `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and enable `cors`